# Action script HTMLLoader not loading

Tags: flash, air

I am developing and AIR application to view and print a PDF file.
Using Flash CS6, my code works flawlessly when I choose Publish Preview. But when I publish the AIR app it does not seem to execute the HTMLLoader methods.
My Action is placed on the first frame. I am using AIR 2.5 and ActionScript 3.0.
What could I be missing? Thanks

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.html.HTMLLoader;
import flash.html.HTMLPDFCapability;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

button.mouseEnabled = false;
button.alpha = 0.3;
button.buttonMode = true;
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_2);

trace("HTMLLoader.pdfCapability: "+HTMLLoader.pdfCapability);
if (HTMLLoader.pdfCapability == HTMLPDFCapability.STATUS_OK) {
var _htmlLoader:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader();
_htmlLoader.width = 500; 
_htmlLoader.height = 625; 
_htmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onHtmlLoader_COMPLETE);
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("2641.html");
_htmlLoader.load(urlRequest);
addChild(_htmlLoader);
}
else{

}
function onHtmlLoader_COMPLETE(event:Event):void
{
        button.alpha = 1;
        button.mouseEnabled = true;
    }
stop();     
function fl_MouseClickHandler_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{

trace("Mouse clicked");

 _htmlLoader.window.callPdfFunctionFromJavascript('Print');
 nextFrame();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fla file I was using was created in Flash CS3. This was incompatible and I recreated it in Flash CS6. Fixed the problem!